# AOP using Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, spring-aop

I am using this Spring AOP code in my Spring Boot starter project in STS. After debugging this for some time I don't see any problem with the AspectJ syntax. The Maven dependencies are generated by STS for a AOP starter project. Is there a glaring omission in this code like an annotation ? The other problem could be with the AOP starter project or with the way I try to test the code in a `@PostConstruct` method.

I installed AJDT but it appears STS should show AspectJ markers in the IDE on its own. Right ? I don't see the markers. What other AspectJ debugging options are included in STS ? `-Xlint` is what I used in Eclipse/AJDT.

**StateHandler.java**

```java
public class StateHandler<EVENTTYPE extends EventType> {


private State<EVENTTYPE> state;

private Event<EVENTTYPE> event;

public StateHandler(State<EVENTTYPE> state, Event<EVENTTYPE> event) {
    this.state = state;
    this.event = event;
}


public void handle( Event<EVENTTYPE> event ){

    state = state.handle( event );

}

public State<EVENTTYPE> getState() {
    return state;
}

}
```

**DeviceLogger .java**

```java
    @Aspect
    @Component
    public class DeviceLogger {

    private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("Device");


        @Around("execution(* com.devicemachine.StateHandler.*(..))")
        public void log() {
            logger.info( "Logger" );
        }
}
```

**LoggerApplication.java**

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class LoggerApplication {

    private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("Device");


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SpringApplication.run(LoggerApplication.class, args);

    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void log(){
        DeviceState s = DeviceState.BLOCKED;
        StateHandler<DeviceEvent> sh = new StateHandler<DeviceEvent>( s,
                                            Event.block(DeviceEvent.BLOCKED, "AuditMessage") );
        sh.handle(Event.block(DeviceEvent.UNBLOCKED, "AuditMessage"));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are 3 obvious things wrong and 1 not so obvious wrong.

1. Your aspect is wrong and breaks proper method execution. When using an around aspect you must always return `Object` and use a `ProceedingJoinPoint` and call `proceed()` on that.
2. You are creating new instances of classes yourself, Spring, by default, uses proxy based AOP and will only proxy beans it knows.
3. In a `@PostConstruct` method it might be that proxies aren't created yet and that nothing is being intercepted
4. You need to use class based proxies for that to be enabled add `spring.aop.proxy-target-class=true` to your `application.properties`. By default JDK Dynamic Proxies are used which are interface based.

### Fix Aspect

Your current aspect doesn't use a `ProceedingJoinPoint` and as such never does the actual method call. Next to that if you now would have a method that returns a value it would all of a sudden return `null`. As you aren't calling `proceed` on the `ProceedingJoinPoint`.

```
@Around("execution(* com.devicemachine.StateHandler.*(..))")
public Object log(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable {
    logger.info( "Logger" );
    return pjp.proceed();
}
```

### Create a bean to fix proxying and `@PostConstruct`

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class LoggerApplication {

    private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("Device");

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(LoggerApplication.class, args);
        StateHandler<DeviceEvent> sh = context.getBean(StateHandler<DeviceEvent>.class);
        sh.handle(Event.block(DeviceEvent.UNBLOCKED, "AuditMessage"));
    }

    @Bean
    public StateHandler<DeviceEvent> auditMessageStateHandler() {
        return new StateHandler<DeviceEvent>(DeviceState.BLOCKED, Event.block(DeviceEvent.BLOCKED, "AuditMessage") );
    }

}
```

### Add property to enable class proxies

In your `application.properties` in `src\main\resources` add the following property with a value of `true`

```
spring.aop.proxy-target-class=true
```

Comment: I have changed the aspect but something like @Before was not working either. Moreover I was thinking about compile-time weaving using AspectJ. Not proxying. That is not possible ?

Comment: That is an omission in your question, you didn't mention anything about that. If you want to use compile time weaving you don't nee dthe `@Component`. You need to add an `aop.xml` and properly setup compile timeweaving in maven (or gradle). else nothing will be woven.

Comment: I have made all the changes for proxying without any effect.

Comment: Then you must not have done everything or not be using a recent Spring Boot version. You do have AspectJ n your class path (or the `spring-boot-starter-aop` which should enable that). Also make sure that the `LoggerApplication` is either in a super package or the same package as the `@Component` annotated aspect otherwise it won't be detected and do exactly nothing. (Or you simply add it as a `@Bean` to your configuration).

Comment: I had to move it to the same package.It worked. There are @Bean and package restrictions and I had to change code to apply aspects.

Comment: No it isn't you could also add an `@CompontScan` to scan the specific package. `@SpringBootApplication` already has an `@ComponentScan` and starts scanning from the package the `LoggingApplication` class is defined in and its sub packages. It is a good practice to put your application class in some top level package so that all your required packages are scanned.